# Cancel a non cancellable task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following code in the codebase:

```
public async Task<HttpApiResponse> FindUsers(Guid userId)
{
    try
    {
        AccessToken token = tokenService.GetAccessToken();
        channel = channelFactory.CreateChannelWithToken(token);
        HttpApiResponse response = await channel.FindUsers(request);

        return response.ToDto();
    }
}
```

Now I like to use CancellationToken here, but im not quite sure if I have done it right:

```
public async Task<HttpApiResponse> FindUsers(Guid userId, CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<decimal>();

        ct.Register(() =>
        {
            // We received a cancellation message, cancel the TaskCompletionSource.Task
            taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
        });

        AccessToken token = await tokenService.GetAccessToken();
        
        await Task.WhenAny(token, taskCompletionSource.Task).ContinueWith(async token => 
        {
            channel = channelFactory.CreateChannelWithToken(token);
            HttpApiResponse response = await channel.FindUsers(request);

            return response.ToDto();
        });   
    }
}
```

The reason why Im not sure is because Im not really sure of how I should handle `await channel.FindUsers(request);` inside `ContinueWith`. Do I need to handle it, since I already handle it when getting the token?

Comment: Check out this article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really cancel an API that doesn't supports cancellation but you can use the `TaskCompletionSource` to return from your `FindUsers` method before the calls to `GetAccessToken` and `FindUsers` have completed if that's what you want.

The below overload will throw an `OperationCanceledException` if the `CancellationToken` is cancelled before the current implementation/overload of `FindUsers` returns a value:

```
public async Task<HttpApiResponse> FindUsers(Guid userId, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<decimal>();
    using (ct.Register(() => taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled()))
    {
        var findUsersTask = FindUsers(userId);
        await Task.WhenAny(findUsersTask, taskCompletionSource.Task);
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return findUsersTask.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JuggernautDev: In your current implementation, you can't cancel and return from the method before `GetAccessToken` has completed.

Comment: hmm, what do you mean?

Comment: You call `await tokenService.GetAccessToken()` before you await the `taskCompletionSource.Task`. Anyway, I believe I have already answered your question and showed you an example. What's your current issue?

Comment: Nah, It was wrong. See my updated question. Im not awaitng tokenService.GetAccessToken(). BUt is it still wrong? I jsut want to know whats wrong wth my implementaion :)

Comment: Still wrong because you cannot cancel while `FindUsers` is running. See my example...